# How to profile a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, flask, profiling, jinja2

The Flask app I am profiling spends a long time rendering its Jinja2 templates.

I have installed [flask lineprofilerpanel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-DebugToolbar-LineProfilerPanel) which is interesting but unfortunately does not let me drill down into the template rendering to see where all the time is spent.

What is the best way to profile a Jinja2 template?

Comment: @akai: I don't know flask but it looks like python. [*This should work.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)

Comment: I think in the profiler in the flask-debugtoolbar you may see all the methods invoked. If you filter manually those having jinja2 in front (i.e. <jinja2\runtime.py:169(call)>) you may have an estimate of the rendering time.

Comment: possibly a related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618827/optimizing-jinja2-environment-creation

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The answer is very interesting but it seems it doesn't help in this case. I tried it out but the stacktrace somehow reports the process is stopped at a mere html line - that is, no-python line in the jinja2 template - and some jinja2 internal code follows, without showing which template line was being rendered before the interruption.

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov Although that doesn't work if the slow function isn't from jinja2 (e.g. from flask), I feel that looking through the profiling result is the "best" way anyway, maybe...

Comment: @intrepidhero As long as I know, flask compiles jinja2 templates only once if it's not updated (and the OP is interested in the use case in flask, so am I).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question. I don't normally have much use for a profiler so this was a good excuse to learn. Following the example here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile I coded up a simple example of profiling a jinja template.

```
import cProfile as profile
import pstats
import StringIO

import jinja2
import time

pr = profile.Profile()

def slow():
    time.sleep(2)
    return "Booga!"

template = jinja2.Template(r'''
    {% for i in RANGE1 %}<h1>hello world {{ i}}</h1>{% endfor %}
    {% for i in RANGE2 %}<h1>foo bar {{ i}}</h1>{% endfor %}
    {{ SLOW() }}
        '''
        )

# here is the bit we want to profile
pr.enable()
context = {"RANGE1": range(1000000), "RANGE2":range(100), "SLOW":slow}
template.render(context)
pr.disable()


s = StringIO.StringIO()
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats("cumulative")
ps.print_stats()
print(s.getvalue())
```

Here is a snippet of the report:

```
         1000130 function calls in 2.448 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.438    2.438 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py:974(render)
        1    0.122    0.122    2.438    2.438 {method 'join' of 'unicode' objects}
  1000104    0.315    0.000    2.317    0.000 <template>:5(root)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.002    2.002 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/runtime.py:169(call)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.002    2.002 profilej.py:10(slow)
        1    2.002    2.002    2.002    2.002 {time.sleep}
        2    0.010    0.005    0.010    0.005 {range}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py:1015(new_context)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/runtime.py:55(new_context)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/runtime.py:115(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {hasattr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py:59(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/nodes.py:81(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/runtime.py:149(resolve)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/runtime.py:126(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {callable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'iteritems' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
```

As I said I don't have much experience interpreting the output of profilers but I think in this example you can see the program spends a little over 2 seconds on time.sleep as expected, which is called by slow(). The rest of the of the time is taken up by join. I assume that  is how Jinja2 processes my two for loops.

Adapting this example into a flask application shouldn't be too hard, just add the profiling bit around the template generation step and write the report to a file. Perhaps you could even extract your templates from the web application and profile them outside of flask.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Well, I think this is the same as what flask-debugtoolbar gives.

Answer (score 1):

For a multi-threaded application like a running Flask server I find that the usual Python profiling tools aren't that great.

I have had good results with [yappi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yappi) which was designed for multithreaded apps.  It's pretty straightforward:

```
import yappi
yappi.start()

   [.. do stuff ..]

yappi.stop()
yappi.convert2pstats(yappi.get_func_stats()).dump_stats('myfile.pstats')
```

That saves profile data in a `pstats` compatible file so you can inspect it interactively in python:

```
>>> import pstats 
>>> s = pstats.Stats('myfile.pstats')
>>> s.strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumtime').print_stats()
```

If you want to be clever you can put the `start()` bit and the `stop()` bit in Flask handlers so you can hit a URL to start profiling, drive your app, then hit a different URL to stop profiling and write out the stats file.

Comment: I tried this, too, but I found this doesn't help any more than flask-debugtoolbar does (at least in terms of jinja2 rendering).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a quick "hacky" way to profile certain Jinja snippet render times, I found an easy way of doing it.

Add this to the main app file:

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(now=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Add this around the snippet you want to time:

```
{% set rendertime = now() %}

{% for x in test_list %}
   {{... do stuff }}
{% endfor %}

<span>Render Time: {{now()-rendertime}}</span>
```