# Jinja2 pre compiled templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, jinja2

I am new to Google App Engine and we need to manage an app deployed with python and `jinja2` templates on Flask. Served templates are compiled in `.py` files.
Question is how do you get those compiled templates. (why compiled templates: look background link below)

Found `jinja2` [precompiler](https://github.com/MiCHiLU/jinja2-precompiler) but still not fully understood how it works.
Source templates files are in folders and subfolders structure. Compiled templates are all inside one folder and filename have this format

```
templates_compiled/tmpl_0ae38b417019b95e730f3e796c4326326a2b053f.py
```

I assume templates are compiled before deploy to `GAE` but can not find the methodology.

Spent days looking for tutorial but couldn't find.

Regards

Edited: more [background information jinja2 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618827/optimizing-jinja2-environment-creation)

Comment: Are you using Django, Flask or another framework ?

Comment: The project uses Flask. I have source templates and need to deploy compiled templates... procedure to get there?..

Comment: You probably don't need to precompile templates.  I've been using Jinja2 templates for about 10 years and I didn't even know that precompiling was a thing until I just googled it.

Comment: I assumed that. But deployed app on GAE serve compiled templates. Jinja has a force_compiled flag on config.py but changing it, have no effect, keeps reading tmpl_().py inside 'compiled_templates/' folder and not ().html inside 'templates/'

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to use precompiled templates?

Comment: There is a discussion [here] (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pocoo-libs/dIsNICT4j2Q)

Comment: If I understand you correctly: You didn't upload the pre-compiled templates to GAE. Instead, you upload the HTML to GAE and you expect Jinja2 to compile the HTML templates into .py code and then serve the templates. But, Jinja is not pre-compiling the templates and is instead trying to load the non existent pre-compiled .py templates? Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. I do not have any experience on GAE or Jinja, so I am trying to figure it out the procedure to modify jinja templates on the app and serve those modified templates.
From what I read, leads me to this options: a) modify templates on debug mode on local Dev, compile and then upload. b) upload modified templates and jinja compile on app.
What is the standard procedure a or b, and how you do it? That is the main question.
Thank you!